# Python syntax error using django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and my code is giving me a syntax error therefore not running and i for one cannot figure out what is up with the syntax could anyone point it out for me please?

Im using Python 3.3 currently.

My code

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView
from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                        url(r'^'), ListView.as_view(
                                queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
                                template_name = "blog.html")),
)
```

My compiler says the syntax error is on the final line where the ) is

Thanks

Comment: You have a comma and then the last closing brackets..

Comment: remove redundant ) after url pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your parenthesis mixed up. It should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', ListView.as_view(
            queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
            template_name = "blog.html")),
    # more url patterns
)
```

The `ListView.as_view()` result should be the second argument to the `url()` call.

Comment: Thank you very much worked like a charm :) also thanks for quick response.